# TableView sorting items (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created this viewController:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SelectClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var list : [QCategoryy] = [QCategoryy]()
    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
    var limit = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        self.title = "Categories"
        list = NearbyPlaces.getCategories()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        list.sort() { $0.views > $1.views}
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func doneTapp(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: nil)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "CATEGORY_CELL"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
        let rowIsSelected = selectedIndexPaths != nil && selectedIndexPaths!.contains(indexPath)
       /* cell.accessoryType = rowIsSelected ? .checkmark : .none  */
        cell.accessoryType = list[indexPath.row].isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    let nearbySearchSegueIdentifier = "goToMcourse"

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

        /* self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: list[indexPath.row])  */
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        if let sr = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            if sr.count == limit {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message:
                    "You are limited to \(limit) selections", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {action in }))
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return nil
            }
        }

        return indexPath
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == nearbySearchSegueIdentifier {
            guard let category = sender as? QCategoryy else {
                return
            }
            if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
                if let vc : CourseClass2 = segue.destination as? CourseClass2 {
                    vc.category = category

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension QCategoryy {
    private static let ketPrefix = "category-"

    var views:Int {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: QCategoryy.ketPrefix + name)
        }
    }

    func markView() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(views + 1, forKey: QCategoryy.ketPrefix + name)
    }
}
```

where there is a simple tableView, where I can select a line and go to the next VC

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

    /* self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: list[indexPath.row])  */
}
```

with this performSegue

```
/* self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: list[indexPath.row])  */
```

with a different result depending on the row I had pressed before. Now I put that you can select multiple cells and consequently then go ahead in the next VC there is a button

```
@IBAction func doneTapp(_ sender: Any) 
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: nil)
}
```

to push, but just do not know why, do not consider the selected rows, so when I click the button it sends me to the next page as if I had not selected any rows. What's the cause of the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: I can't seem to fully understand what you wanna do. Do you want to select multiple rows and then tap the `Done` button before proceeding to the next screen? Make it clearer.

Comment: @Glenn yes i'm trying to do this

Comment: what is the `CourseClass2`?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ is the viewController after this

Comment: the `peformSegue` is called from `doneTapp`?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ now that I've add the option to select multiple rows yes, before it was called with self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: list[indexPath.row]) in DidSelectRowAt

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is clear - `doneTap` calls `performSegue` with `sender` set to `nil`:

```
@IBAction func doneTapp(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: nil)
}
```

In `prepareForSegue` you set the category on the target view controller, but before that you have a `guard` statement checking if the `sender` is a selected category. Since in this case you have set `sender` to `nil`, this guard will cause the code to skip the setting of the category, and you code behaves as if you haven't set the category at all (because you really did not set it).

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

```
    if segue.identifier == nearbySearchSegueIdentifier {
        guard let category = sender as? QCategoryy else {
            return
        }
        if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            if let vc : CourseClass2 = segue.destination as? CourseClass2 {
                vc.category = category

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My recommendation is to drop the `guard`, and instead use `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` to determine which categories to send to the next view controller, and use them, e.g.:

```
// this will get you the list of selected categories, or if none is selected, an empty list
let selectedCategories: [QCategoryy] = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.map({ (indexPath) -> QCategoryy in
    return list[indexPath.row]
}) ?? []
vc.categories = selectedCategories
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, you're right! but how can i use tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows in the prepare to determine which categories to send? can you show me please?

Comment: oh great! i only take this error "Cannot assign value of type '[QCategoryy]' to type 'QCategoryy?'" in this line   vc.categories = selectedCategories

Comment: obviously you have to change the implementation of the `CourseClass2` to support an array (a list if you want) of categories instead of a single category.. before you had a property `var category: QCategoryy?` which you used to setup the view controller's state, now you want to have `var categories: [QCategoryy] = []`, because instead of a single category, you will get a list of selected categories.. and of course, you will need to modify the whole `CourseClass2` implementation to use the list instead of a single category